# Java/Android - Combine custom extension files into one file

Tags: java, android, stream

I am serializing my custom classes to  custom extension files in android system. I am creating a file for each custom class and saving them in sd card of android system. What i wanna do is i want to combine them into big single file and be able to get each file whenever i need from that one big file.

Which way should i follow?

//Sample of how i write

```
    public static void writeExpenses(ArrayList<Expense> obj) throws    IOException{

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(folder +"/"+DefaultValues.backupExpenseFileName);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    fout.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class containing all of the objects you need to serialize, and serialize that:

```
class FullFile {
    List<Expense> list
    ObjectA objectA;
    ObjectB objectB
}
```

....

```
 oos.writeObject(new FullFile(...));
```

And for deserializing:

```
 FullFile file = (FullFile) ois.readObject();
```

all your objects can now be accessed via your new class

Comment: Then how will retreiving(deserializing) be like? How can i know that cursor is reading deser.. which object? It is written that only one public class can be serialized to a file.